# snapcraft create-key taking forever to complete

Tags: snapcraft

Its taking forever to create key when trying to create key using 'snapcraft create-key' or 'snap create-key'.

I have waited for 30 minutes and still have no success in creating the key.

Does any know how much time should I give to create it? Or is it bug in snapd?

I'm running snapd version 2.26.9.

Comment: I reported this on the snapcraft forums. https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapcraft-create-key-takes-a-while/1595

Comment: I suspect the delay occurs because the key generation requires entropy and the entropy pool is low.  One way to generate entropy is to generate a lot of random input, for example, lots of random keyboard input, or perhaps pinging a host, (ping 8.8.8.8) or exercising the file system.